# How to truncate an email local-part to 'abc...@gmail.com'

Tags: php, regex, email, truncate

I use this little function to truncate strings when needed:

```
function truncate_text($text, $nbrChar = 55, $append='...') {
    if (strlen($text) > $nbrChar) {
        $text = substr($text, 0, $nbrChar);
        $text .= $append;
    } 
    return $text;
}
```

I would like some help to create a new function to truncate email local-parts similar to what is done in Google Groups.

```
abc...@gmail.com
```

This would be especially useful for users using Facebook's proxy email.

```
apps+2189712.12457.7b00f3c9e8bfabbeea8f73@proxymail.facebook.com
```

I guess this new function would use regex to find the `@` and then truncate the local-part to a certain number of characters to generate something like

```
apps+21...@proxymail.facebook.com
```

Any suggestions how to tackle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This function will truncate the first part of the email ( if the @ is found ) and other string if @ not found.

```
function truncate_text($text, $nbrChar = 55, $append='...') {
  if(strpos($text, '@') !== FALSE) {
    $elem = explode('@', $text);
    $elem[0] = substr($elem[0], 0, $nbrChar) . $append;
    return $elem[0] . '@' . $elem[1];
  }
  if (strlen($text) > $nbrChar) {
    $text = substr($text, 0, $nbrChar);
    $text .= $append;
  } 
  return $text;
}

echo truncate_text('apps+2189712.12457.7b00f3c9e8bfabbeea8f73@proxymail.facebook.com', 10);
// will output : apps+21897...@proxymail.facebook.com

echo truncate_text('apps+2189712.12457.7b00f3c9e8bfabbeea8f73proxymail.facebook.com', 10);
// will output : apps+21897...
```

Comment: nice... like the `explode` instead of using regex - let me try this out - thx for the input